# Saving variables from a function to the workspace (matlab)

Tags: matlab, function

I'm a total beginner to Matlab so would really appreciate any tips.

I have a one-output function F, which creates various transitional variables while processing. For example:

```
F=myfun(x1, x2, x3) 

a=f(x1)
b=g(x2) 

F=z(a,b,x1,x2,x3)
end
```

I wish to have these transitional variables a and b available for viewing and editing in the workspace after calling the function. How can I do this?

I played with persistent and global, but it didn't work.

I wish to keep it as a one-output function, as I proceed afterwards to find the roots of F with fsolve (F is a system of non-linear equations).

So in summary the problem is:

```
[x1, fval]=fsolve(@(x1) myfun(x1, x2, x3), x0)

a

Error:
Undefined function or variable 'a'.
```

Many many thanks for any help on this seemingly easy problem.

Comment: Sorry, instead of "z", I meant to write "a" (I edited the question, it should now be correct).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the variable as global **in the workspace** (first) and the function and assign it in the function.

The value of the variable in the workspace should get updated as the function runs.

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly. The trick was to define it global in both the workspace and the function, otherwise it doesn't update.